# Detaching default functionality from gradle lifecycle tasks

Tags: java, gradle, continuous-integration, checkstyle

**Tl;dr**

Is there a way to detach specific plugin behavior (such as checkstyle's check behavior) from existing gradle lifecycle tasks (gradle check, in this particular case)?

**Longer version**

In our current gradle Java project setup, we've included [checkstyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) as one of our plugins for static code checking. It currently runs as a part of Jenkins pipeline through gradle's *build* task. While this has mostly worked out for what we've needed - namely running our tests and making sure we're sticking to code standards - I've also noticed that we could make our feedback loop a little faster if we could run **just** the checkstyle's plugin's checks **before** build kicks in the tests.

To do so, as far as I understand, we'd have to create a custom task that runs only the checkstyle functions checkstyleMain and checkstyleTest **and** decouple the default checkstyle behavior from gradle's build lifecycle task. I've been looking through both [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) and the [checkstyle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html)'s docs, but quickly found I'm out of my depth.

Code:

```
plugins {
    id "checkstyle"
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion "8.24"
    configFile file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
}

checkstyleMain {
    source = "src/main/java"
}
checkstyleTest {
    source = "src/test/java"
}
```

That is everything checkstyle related inside of build.gradle, the check task itself isn't customized.

Comment: The question seems fairly clear, but it would be helpful if you could include a small code example from your Gradle build that shows the relevant parts of your current configuration, and where the plugin is being added.